# Facebook Javascript API: '/me/albums' not working for other users

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the '/me/albums' for my website app in JavaScript. It returns the correct array when I use the app but not for other users.

Also, I have put the { scope: 'user_photos' } in FB.login(), but it doesn't ask the user for Photos permission when they log in.

For getting access_token, I'm using this:

```
accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
```

Comment: You need to submit your application for Review (user_photos ) by Facebook team before it is available to users. First you need to test this feature by one of the profile available in your App Role section. If the feature is working as expected you need to submit for review. Once Facebook team approved it will be available to all users,

Comment: @AzeezKallayi So, there's nothing wrong with the method, right? I am starting a request submission now. Thank you.

Comment: Yea you can submit for review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most permissions need to get reviewed before the can be used by everyone. Without review, they only work for users with a role in the App.

There should actually be a warning text whenever you try to login as an App Admin or Developer.

Official docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review